# Como funciona o async/await em Rust?

Tags: característica-linguagem, async, assincronismo, rust

A ideia de `async`/`await` tem se tornado comum em várias linguagens (C#, JavaScript etc).

Parece que o Rust adotou recentemente (na edição 2018 do Rust) a ideia de `async`/`await`, em conjunto ao conceito de `Future` (que, até onde entendi, é análogo a uma `Promise` do JavaScript).

Gostaria de saber como o `async`/`await` funciona em Rust. Se necessário, também brevemente sobre `Future`.

Answer (score 2):

Quando você usa `async` em uma função em rust:

```rust
async fn teste() {
    ...
}
```

é o mesmo que dizer que essa função retorna uma Future. Por "baixo" é como se ela ficasse:

```rust
fn teste() -> impl Future {
    ...
}
```

e a crate [futures](https://crates.io/crates/futures) te permite usar tanto `async` quanto `await`, pra criar ou resolver uma função assíncrona e esperar um resultado dentro de outra função assíncrona.

A crate `futures` também vem com a função  `futures::executor::block_on` que serve como um executor, pra você rodar suas funções assíncronas.

Exemplo:

```rust
use blocking::{block_on, unblock};
use futures_lite::*;
use std::fs;

async fn read_file() {
    let contents = unblock!(fs::read_to_string("file.txt"))?;
    println!("{}", contents);
    io::Result::Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    block_on(read_file);
}
```